# Wired connection keeps disconnecting and connecting a few seconds later

Tags: networking, ethernet

Hello I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 today and my wired connection keeps disconnecting and reconnecting a few seconds later. It works fine on windows. I am kind of a noob so I don't not know what logs I need to submit. Any answers are appreciated!

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: nm-connection-editor    
kill the wired connection and let it make a new one, or make a new one.
also to force the same name to be used into grub

net.ifnames=0 biosvname=0

or search here for those terms.